# Set theory - induction - countable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

need help with the following question:

Let $S \subseteq P(\mathbb N)$ be defined inductively so that:

- $\mathbb N \in S$
- for all$ ~ a \in \mathbb N \Longrightarrow \mathbb N\setminus\{a\}\in S$
- for all $A,B \in S \Longrightarrow A\cap B \in S$

Prove that if $A\subseteq \mathbb N~ $ and $~ \mathbb N $ \ $A$ is finite then $A \in S$

thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{N} \in S$ imply that $\mathbb{N} \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: it was supposed to be $P(\mathbb N)$ , i fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove it by induction on $\#(\mathbb{N}\setminus A)$:

- If $\#(\mathbb{N}\setminus A)=0$, then $A=\mathbb N$ and therefore $A\in S$.
- Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and suppose that $\#(\mathbb{N}\setminus A)=n\implies A\in S$. Then, if $\#(\mathbb{N}\setminus A)=n+1$, take $a\in(\mathbb{N}\setminus A)$ and let $A^\star=A\cup\{a\}$. Then $\#(\mathbb{N}\setminus A^\star)=n$ and therefore $A^\star\in S$. So,$$A=A^\star\cap(\mathbb{N}\setminus\{a\})\in S$$

Comment: why when $ |A| = n \longrightarrow \mathbb N \setminus A = \mathbb N$ ?

Comment: @bliblo I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: but you havent proved that $A \in S$

Comment: @bliblo I don't understand your objection. I proved by induction on $\#A$ that, for every finite set $A$, $\mathbb{N}\setminus A\in S$. In order to do that, I proved that the statement is true when $\#A=0$ and then I proved that **if** the statement is true when $\#A=n$, **then** it is true when $\#A=n+1$. What is your objection exactly?

Comment: You need to prove that $A \in S $ not that $\mathbb N \setminus A \in S $
Maybe i understood your proof wrong but i see that you've proved that $\mathbb N \setminus A \in S$

Comment: @bliblo What do you think now?

Comment: Looks good, thank you!

Comment: @bliblo If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

If $B\subset\mathbb N$ is finite, then there exists a unique $n\in\mathbb N$, such that $|A|=n$ and a bijection $f:\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}\to A$.

In Set Theory $0=\varnothing$ and $n=\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$.

Let 
$$
J=\{k\in n: f[k]\in S\}
$$
We want to show that $J=n$.

Clearly, $f[0]=\mathbb N\in S$. If $J\ne n$, then there exists a least $m\le n$, such that $f[m]\not\in S$. But this also means that $m>0$ and $f[m-1]\in S$

Note that
$$
f[m]=f[m-1]\cup\{f(m)\}
$$
and
$$
\mathbb N\setminus f[m]=(\mathbb N\setminus f[m-1])\cap(\mathbb N\setminus \{f(m)\})
$$
But $\mathbb N\setminus f[m-1],\,\mathbb N\setminus \{f(m)\}\in S$, and thus $\mathbb N\setminus f[m]\in S$. Contradiction.